# Express application - delegate access

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web-applications

I've created a basic node/express application.

The user can register on the /register route, and the data is posted to /users/register. The user is then redirected to the login page and can access a protected route after successful login.

MongoDB as database if you wondered.

However, I want to implement a 'Delegate access' function. Consider this example:

User registers to the site ->

```
const user = {
name: req.body.name,
email: req.body.email,
password: req.body.password,
access: false
}
```

In my portal I'm fetching all the data from my users collection. From here I have set that for each user I want to display a checkbox determining whether the user access can be granted.

[image]

I struggle to come up with a decent solution as to how I can update this for the multiple users. As I don't 'know' who the user is after the data is rendered to front end.

My wanted solution is to 'check' the checkboxes to assign the user .access = true and then click an update button, then the user can log in.

I'm using passport to authenticate the user, with local strategy.

Also if anyone has any experience with a smtp service that can integrate with this to email users upon account creation and then email the user to notify that they have gained access.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Front end script to render the users from db.

```
    const container = document.querySelector('.dataSection')
    fetch('/users/all')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => logUsers(data))
    
    const users = []

    function renderUsers(data) {
        data.forEach((data, index) => {
            users.push(data)
            const userRow = document.createElement('div')
            userRow.className = 'columns user' + data._id 
            userRow.innerHTML =
            `
                    <div class="column">${data.name}</div> 
                    <div class="column is-4">${data.email}</div>
                    <div class="column">${data.company}</div>
                    <div class="column">${data.position}</div>
                `
            if(data.access) {
                userRow.innerHTML += 
                `<div class="column is-1 field">
                    <label class="checkbox" style="text-align: center;">
                        <input class="is-checkradio is-success" type="checkbox" checked>
                    </label>
                </div>`
            } else {
                userRow.innerHTML +=
                `
                <div class="column is-1 field">
                    <label class="checkbox" style="text-align: center;">
                        <input class="is-checkradio is-success" type="checkbox">
                    </label>
                </div>
                `

            }
            container.appendChild(userRow)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to provide access to User only when you provide or set "access" property to true? Do you have any condition that makes you think to allow user to have access? Also, where are you getting this checkbox, do you have any other page?

Comment: Yes, only when access is true. The thought behind this is that the content the users will be served is considered "sensitive". So only eligble users should be able to log in. My initial thought was to allow the users to register, and when a user registers, the admins will recieve an email informing this. Then the admin goes to /users, this renders a page displaying all the users in the database, renders name, email, company and also the checkbox which specify if user.access is true or not. Then the admin can tick the checkbox and click update. This triggers a new email to be sent to the user.

Comment: I've added the front end script I'm using to render the users.

Comment: "So only eligible users should be able to log in", what is the condition for the user to  be eligible and access the data? Is it the admin who will decide randomly the user that can access the data?

Comment: Yes, it's based on the information in the user object. Name, company and position/role.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this question can have multiple answers, but at the moment this could be a good fit based on the inputs you provided. It can have multiple steps to follow. Let me go through it step-by-step:

1. Once a user login on the new route, you will get the user Details and save it to DB with access:false.
2. Once the information is saved, you can send email to the admin using [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/). Provide a link that can help admin to navigate to the Dashboard. Also, send an email to the user that your request is registered and it will be considered by the admin.

3) (optional) Now, when you load the dashboard, you should create three lists: Approved, Rejected, Awaiting based on access (true, false(when user login), not approved). You should create a dropdown list for access: Approve, Rejected. (This is just a suggestion)

4. Now, when you load the dashboard, you can create a checkbox, by default it should be unchecked. Once you check the box an email(using nodemailer) will be sent to the user stating that you can login now with the credentials.
5. If you have multiple users at a same time login on your system, you can actually create a script for the dashboard which checks the condition for new users(that might be based on some business logic), and it should be enabled using a button on Dashboard (Approve All). All the user based on the business logic, an email should be sent to them.

Now, as you haven't mentioned condition on what user will be approved, it will require human intervention to check if the provided information is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks for the input, appreciate it! :)

Comment: Does it make any sense :) ?

Comment: Yes, but I was actually looking for a more technical perspective. Like what would be a good solution to post the changes to the users.

Each user row is a div. So my thought was to have an event listener on the checkboxes and based on their value update the database with their id/email and access accordingly.